# Why is cfreturn null?

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfc

I proxied a call to a cfc which does an ftp "get" to a local temp file. Then it reads the file and is supposed to return the file content as a string. I know the code works, when I pull it out of cfc into a regular cfm file it does exactly what is expected. However, in my proxy `callBackHandler`, the cfc result appears to be null. Here is the proxy code:

```
    <cfajaxproxy cfc="ftpfunc" jsclassname="jsobj" />
    function getFTP() {
       ...
       var instance = new jsobj();
       instance.setCallbackHandler(ftpSuccess);
       instance.setErrorHandler(ftpError);
       instance.setReturnFormat('plain');
       instance.getJCL(lpar,remoteFile,userName,password); 
    }
```

.. and then the callbackHandler, which should have the string returned from the cfc:

```
    function ftpSuccess(ftpReturn)
    {
     // error thrown right here: "ftpReturn is Null"
       if (ftpReturn.length==0)
           { alert("Your FTP Get returned a blank file"); }
     }
```

Is there a particular syntax to be used? For example when the return type is a struct or query you have to use something like `ftpReturn.DATA`. How about a straight string?

Thanks for any help

**EDIT: This is the cfc**

```
<cffunction name="getJCL" output="false" access="remote" securejson="true">
    <cfargument name="lpar" type="string" required="yes">
    <cfargument name="remoteFile" type="string" required="yes">
    <cfargument name="userName" type="string" required="yes">
    <cfargument name="password" type="string" required="yes">
    <cfset var ftpReturn = "">

    <cfftp action="open"
        connection="getConnection"
        password="#arguments.password#"
        secure="yes" 
        server="#arguments.lpar#" 
        stopOnError="no" 
        timeout="30" 
        username="#arguments.username#">

    <cfset tempFile="D:\myDir\#RandRange(10000000,99999999)#.tmp">

    <cfftp action="getFile"
        connection="getConnection"
        localFile="#tempFile#"
        remoteFile="#arguments.remoteFile#"
        transferMode="auto">

    <cffile action = "read" file = "#tempFile#" variable = "Message">

    <cfset ftpReturn = Message>

    <cfreturn ftpReturn>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Show the cfc so we can see what's beig returned.

Comment: Install Fiddler (http://fiddler2.com) and use that to watch the request/response. The inspectors (bottom right quarter of the Fiddler UI) has a JSON tab which will show you the structure of the data being returned. If that shows nothing, use the RAW tab to show exactly what the server is returning. That'll get you to knowing whether it's a server or client problem

Comment: In my experience you get nulls if the variable gets deinstantiated.  So if the CFFILE reads a file of 0 length, Message may have a Java pointer to null.

Comment: the file is definitely not blank. in fact, if i remove the callbackHandler function, i can see in the Console\Response tab of fireBug the actual file content, which is "test"

Comment: i've installed fiddler too, under the json tag i only get "The response does not contain valid JSON text"

Comment: Have you tried setting returnFormat="JSON" in the remote function?

Comment: You haven't var-scoped `Message`, though there's no reason not to assign `variable="ftpReturn"` directly.  

Also, change `RandRange(10000000,99999999)` to `createUuid()` to guarantee unique filenames.

Answer (score 0):

> if i remove the callbackHandler function, i can see in the Console\Response tab of fireBug the actual file content, which is "test"
>   ...
>   i've installed fiddler too, under the json tag i only get "The response does not contain valid JSON text"

So you're not currently returning valid JSON?

It may or not be a bug in CF that it passes null if it receives invalid content (rather than throwing an error), but change the file contents to something that [validates](http://jsonlint.com/) and maybe it'll work?

You could also try something like...

```
<cftry>
    <cfset deserializeJson(ftpReturn) />
    <cfcatch>
        <cfset ftpReturn = '{"error":"invalid json"}' />
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

...to detect inside the function if it's valid JSON and if not return appropriate message.

Don't forget you need `output=false` on the cfcomponent tag itself, otherwise you might still get whitespace added from the area outside the functions.

A couple of other things - you're not actually using the `Message` variable, so just do:

```
<cffile action = "read" file = "#tempFile#" variable = "ftpReturn">
```

Also, random numbers are *not* guaranteed to be unique, so there's a small chance of getting data corruption unless you switch to:

```
<cfset tempFile="D:\myDir\#createUuid()#.tmp">
```

Comment: thanks, i've tried everything you suggested. the json error trapping didn't get anything, the null error is the same. changed the cfc function returnformat to "plain" so as to match the statement in the js function (prevent the cfc from serializing the result), same result.

Comment: What happens if you change the appropriate line of the JS to `instance.setCallbackHandler(function(){console.log(arguments)});` ?

Comment: it returns 0  null
           1 undefined